# MSAccess 2013 odd rounding behavior in queries

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013, rounding-error

I'm pretty confused about the rounding function not working as expected when used in queries.  *Update, I think i found the problem, listed below, but am not sure why it should have worked this way*

Basically, I have a value [Amount] that is type Single, and often has 5 digits usable precision, but in certain queries I want to round it to two digits, other times keep it to 5.  What I'm finding is that even if [Amount] has only two decimals actual data, the query is returning 12 or 13, almost like its working in reverse, where it "unrounds" it to a slightly lower number...see below.    I even tried to use an integer rounding function that first multiplies the value by 100000 then takes the integer, then divides by 100000, and I see similar behavior: it is almost like Access is storing the data in a different precision than its actually presenting it

Never seen this before, not sure how to correct for this and make it as expected.  BTW, if I use the same query and make a table from it, these 12 digit values are put into the new table.

Any ideas appreciated, cause I'm trying to fix my math to 5 digits in some places and this inaccuracy is making it impossible to know what the real value should be. I put a few sample values above the initial 2 digit number so you can see how confusing the behavior is.

SQL:

```
SELECT amount, Round([amount],2) AS Round_2_Digits, Round([amount],5) AS Round_5_digits, Int([amount]*100000)/100000 AS Integer_5 digits from FCS
```

```
amount     Round_2_Digits     Round_5_digits    Integer_5 digits
95.88       95.879997253418     95.879997253418     95.87999
95.88001    95.879997253418     95.880012512207     95.88001
95.881      95.879997253418     95.8809967041016    95.88099
95.889      95.8899993896484    95.8889999389648    95.88899
```

---

Update:  as I was writing this, I wondered if the Single data type was the problem, and when I changed it Double, first the source data [Amojnt] definitely changed, as shown below, then when I fixed the source [Amount] to the original, the rounding function worked perfectly. In fact it worked even with the weird data, since it was such a small amount that it was off.

So is the Single data type the culprit?  I was using it because I was trying to minimize data storage, but clearly Double is the way to go.  anyone know why?  thanks!

Here is the updated query after I changed the data type to double:

```
amount         Round_2_Digits   Round_5_digits  Integer_5 digits
95.879997253418     95.88       95.88           95.87999
95.880012512207     95.88       95.88001        95.88001
95.8809967041016    95.88       95.881          95.88099
95.8889999389648    95.89       95.889          95.88899
```

Here is the query after I reset the original data to what it should have been

```
amount     Round_2_Digits   Round_5_digits  Integer_5 digits
95.88       95.88            95.88          95.88
95.88001    95.88            95.88001       95.88001
95.881      95.88            95.881         95.881
95.889      95.89            95.889         95.889
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never rely on the native `Round` for any precision data as it is quite buggy. Also, it performs *Banker's Rounding* which may not be what you wish.

For your case, you could use the `RoundMid` function found at [VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round).

Comment: thanks for your info, interesting about the roundmid function, have to check it out.  but it appears that its more a function of the Single data type than the rounding function.  works fine if the data is type Double, just weird data for the same query and other code using Single.

Comment: _Single_ should always be used with care. But such care doesn't make _Round_ work fine; it is only useful for non-critical rounding.